# In ios how do I set a google map to a specified region using only latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: ios, google-maps

### Update:

It seems like if I use `GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 0.0)`  I get what I expect (the map coordinates match what I specified, with no padding).

I went back and re-read the docs, but I don't see anything to imply that simply calling `GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds)` would add some padding.  Did I miss something in the documentation?

### Original Question:

In iOS I am trying to set a map to a specific set of coordinates.

I am creating a cameraUpdate object via `GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds)`

but after I apply the update via moveCamera() the visible region of the map is larger than the bounds I set.  Also note that I checked the padding and it is set to 0 (ok, I only checked one edge but I did not set the padding at all)

Here is the code I am using and the log output.  You can see that the new region is larger than what I asked for , but the aspect ratio is pretty close to what the input was.

How to I set the map to a specific set of coordinates?

BTW, in Android I do this with

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = ameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, padding);
```

and that seems to work fine.

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: lowerLeft, coordinate: upperRight)
println("padding  = \(mapView.padding.bottom)")
let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds)
println("bounds sw lon = \(bounds.southWest.longitude)")
println("bounds ne lon = \(bounds.northEast.longitude)")
println("bounds sw lat = \(bounds.southWest.latitude)")
println("bounds ne lat = \(bounds.northEast.latitude)")
let boundsLatSpan = bounds.northEast.latitude - bounds.southWest.latitude
let boundsLonSpan = bounds.northEast.longitude - bounds.southWest.longitude
println("bounds lat span / lon span = \(boundsLatSpan / boundsLonSpan)")
mapView.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
println("bounds after setting map near left lon = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().nearLeft.longitude)")
println("bounds after setting map near right lon = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().nearRight.longitude)")
println("bounds after setting map far left lon = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().farLeft.longitude)")
println("bounds after setting map far right lon = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().farRight.longitude)")
println("bounds after setting map near left lat = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().nearLeft.latitude)")
println("bounds after setting map near right lat = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().nearRight.latitude)")
println("bounds after setting map far left lat = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().farLeft.latitude)")
println("bounds after setting map far right lat = \(mapView.projection.visibleRegion().farRight.latitude)")
let vr = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
let viewLatSpan = vr.farLeft.latitude - vr.nearLeft.latitude
let viewLonSpan = vr.farRight.longitude - vr.farLeft.longitude
println("lat span / lon span = \(viewLatSpan/viewLonSpan)")
```

here is the output

```
padding  = 0.0
bounds sw lon = -79.7475584596395
bounds ne lon = -68.7612316757441
bounds sw lat = 35.6926899321375
bounds ne lat = 47.1044623446186
bounds lat span / lon span = 1.03872501127577
bounds after setting map near left lon = -81.1208491399884
bounds after setting map near right lon = -67.3879409953952
bounds after setting map far left lon = -81.1208491399884
bounds after setting map far right lon = -67.3879409953952
bounds after setting map near left lat = 34.1267012281634
bounds after setting map near right lat = 34.1267012281634
bounds after setting map far left lat = 48.3884976942429
bounds after setting map far right lat = 48.3884976942429
lat span / lon span = 1.03851247790473
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_update.html#aa5b05606808272f9054c54af6830df3e) does say that "The bounds will have a default padding of 64 points." If need you padding, just use `GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 0.0)` method.

Comment: Wow, I guess I did miss that.  The only thing I can think of is that I did not see the "+" next to the method name, and did not realize there was more to the method documentation than " Returns a GMSCameraUpdate that transforms the camera such that the specified bounds are centered on screen at the greatest possible zoom level. "